# Pre-load a JS file in puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, browser-automation

I have a javascript file which spoofs browser properties. how can I preload I before loading any website?

I used to work with nightmare JS. we are using this

command

```sh
node main.js data-spoof.js "$proxy"
```

inside main.js file

```js
var args = process.argv.slice(2);
var proxystr = 'socks4://' + args[1].replace(/"/g, '');




webPreferences: {
    preload: path.resolve(args[0]),
      },
switches: {
    'proxy-server': proxystr,
      },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can  [`page.evaluateOnNewDocument(pageFunction[, ...args])`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluateonnewdocumentpagefunction-args) help?

Comment: is there anyway for websites to know ? that i'm using puppeteer?  :) If yes, is there anyway to prevent it ? :)   websites = big companies like google.com

Comment: I am afraid this is a complicated question with a large number of quirks. There is a constant cat-and-mouse play between websites and scrapers. See more: https://github.com/paulirish/headless-cat-n-mouse